# python on raspberry pi 3b+: "no module named requests", despite the module being installed

Tags: python, python-requests, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

first of all - I'm a newbie when it comes to Linux stuff. I follow commands and try to look up problems that I encounter along the way. I tried the same approach with this issue, but nothing has worked so far.

I'm trying to install a program on a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS (version 11 Bullseye) on a Raspberry Pi 3b+. I'm not sure I can link the github page of the program here, but it's an application that's written mostly in Python. **I have already installed that application successfully on a laptop running an Arch based distro.** There were no such problems there.

I follow install instructions, I download dependencies, I create a virtualenv, activate it, download stuff from requirements.txt and then try to run the program.
Here's where the issue occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

So I try to install requests with

```
sudo pip install requests
```

(while still being in the virtualenv):

```
(venv) pi@pimusic:~ $ sudo pip install requests
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (2020.6.20)
```

So requests is already there, but is not recognized, somehow.
I have tried:

- uninstalling requests from within venv and installing it again
- uninstalling requests from outside venv and trying to install it from inside venv
- uninstalling requests from outside venv and installing it again
- removing everything with "requests" in the filename from /usr/loval/lib/python3.9/dist-packages and installing requests back from inside venv and from outside venv

none of these things worked. I'm stumped, what do I do?

Comment: Difficult to debug this without actually putting my hands on your setup. However, this "smells" of the very common case of "fixing the problem in one place, then testing it in another" (an occurrence I see a lot when supporting users of my software). In this particular case, you mention that you are installing `requests` in your venv. Are you running the Python interpreter from you venv, or could it be that you might be trying to run your code with the global interpreter?

Comment: you will want to activate your virtual environment first and then execute 'python -m pip install requests' or else 'python3 -m pip install requests'.  however, I am not sure if you will know how to activate your virtual environment or not.  If you can find the directory of the virtual environment look for the /bin folder.  inside that folder the command is 'source activate'   and to leave the virtual environment the command is 'deactivate'

Comment: @AmitaiIrron I'm trying to run `/app/venv/bin/python /app/app.py` while being inside venv. I have also tried running it while outside, same result.

@Mark I have tried installing requests with both commands you shared here from inside the virtualenv, I do know how to activate and deactivate.

Comment: use the command env or env | grep PYTHONPATH to see if the path leading to the requests folder is on your PYTHONPATH.  for example my requests folder is inside here /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages and this directory is listed within my PYTHONPATH when the virtual environment is activated